# What is `shuffle_order_engine` for?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, shuffle

I wanted to code a line that shuffles a vector. Auto completion suggested `shuffle_order_engine`, which made me curious what it is, since the name suggests it does what I want.

Usually i shuffle a vector with `std::shuffle(std::begin(v), std::end(v), gen)` where `gen` is the random number generator (usually `mt19937_64`).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/shuffle_order_engine/ sais, that `shuffle_order_engine` is:

> An engine adaptor class template that adapts a pseudo-random number
>   generator Engine type so that the numbers are delivered in a different
>   sequence.

Well, cplusplus.com does not provide an example. Is `shuffle_order_engine` doing the same as my `shuffle` adoption?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  It buffers the output of a pseudo-rng and returns any of the next few results instead of the next.  The results, compared to if you requested a vector of the same size and filled it with that sequence, then shuffled it, are similar but with a slightly-different distribution of permutations.  (I think.)

If what you want is a shuffled random sequence, then sure.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

C++'s `shuffle_order_engine` implements something like a Bays–Durham shuffle, and the Bays–Durham shuffle was designed to *improve the randomness quality* of weak random number generators, not necessarily to behave the same way as a random shuffle of a list.